# rsyslog: can you check if two local variables are equal?

Tags: rhel, rsyslog

**EDIT: More context.**

I have the follow example:

```
set $.dev1IP = 192.168.1.1;
set $.dev2IP = 192.168.1.2;
set $.dev3IP = 192.168.1.3;

set $.sourceIP = $fromhost-ip;
set $.sourceTag = "";

template(name="temp1" type="string" string="/path/to/logDir/%.sourceIP%/%.sourceIP%.%.sourceTag%.log")

ruleset(name="rules1") {
if ($.sourceIP == $.dev1IP) then {
    set $.sourceTag = "tag1";
    do something
} else if ($.sourceIP == $.dev2IP) then {
    set $.sourceTag = "tag2";
    do something
} else if ($.sourceIP == $.dev3IP) then {
    set $.sourceTag = "tag3";
    do something
} else {
    do something if nothing else matches
}
action(type="omfile" dynaFile="temp1")
}
```

This is a more complete code block to show how I know it's not working. I have logs coming in from those IP addresses but the dynamic file generated is named "192.168.1.1..log" when instead it should be named "192.168.1.1.tag1.log".

Running "rsyslogd -N1 -f /etc/rsyslog.conf" results in no errors.

What is the correct conditional statement to make that comparison work?

Comment: Besides the ruleset being defined, there's no other mention of that comparison and rsyslog doesn't return any errors when executing ````rsyslogd -N1````. What am I supposed to look for in the debug?

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: In the template, the properties are missing their `$` sign, eg `%.sourceTag%` should be `%$.sourceTag%`, and the first 3 lines are missing their `set` command.

Comment: While I forgot to write it in this post, I am properly setting the variables in the configuration. The issue is definitely not that it is missing a ````$```` as it is currently working without them. The ````$.sourceTag```` is set to ````""```` and that is why the dynamic file is being named ````$.sourceIP..log````. The if statements are not properly comparing and therefore the ````$.sourceTag```` variable never gets a value. The issue still stands that comparing the ````$.sourceIP```` against a pre-set variable is never returning true. So how do I run that comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a simpler example, setting a local variable outside a ruleset, then accessing it inside the ruleset, and its value was empty. I presume this is a feature, to make ruleset spaces more independent.

I'm not sure what can be done about this and I do not have any suitable counter-examples.  The same is true for `$!var` json-style variables. There is no mention of this in [ruleset concepts](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/multi_ruleset.html).

The extensive debugging you get with `rsyslog -dn` confirms how a variable set with `set $.var1 = "abc";` outside the ruleset is `(null)` inside the ruleset for the evaluation of `if($.var1 == $.mydir)...` where `$.mydir` is set inside the ruleset:

```
eval expr 0x556bdce30480, return datatype 'S':0
    IF
        var '.var1'
      ==
        var '.mydir'
eval expr 0x556bdce30560, type 'CMP_EQ'
eval expr 0x556bdce30390, type 'V'
rainerscript: (json/string) var 202: '(null)'
eval expr 0x556bdce30390, return datatype 'S':0
eval expr 0x556bdce1e2b0, type 'V'
rainerscript: (json/string) var 202: 'abc'
if condition result is 0
```

Comment: The key was to set the local variables within the ruleset. Even using an include() function with variables defined in another file works as long as they are included within the ruleset that references them. Thank you!